# Input type="text" maxlength validation is ignored on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

The `maxlength` attribute on inputs and textareas works fine for user input, but when I modify the value with Javascript or set it via `value="..."` and submit the form afterwards, the validation is not applied:

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" maxlength="5" value="Longer than 5 chars">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Why does this not fail?

Compare with number input, where the form fails as expected:

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="number" max="4" value="8">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#maxlength),

> [maxlength] Constraint validation is only applied when the value is changed by the user.

But why? And can this be solved without Javascript? It seems redundant to validate the maxlength in two different places, first in HTML and second in Javascript.

For which attributes does this validation issue apply? `maxlength`, `minlength`, and more...? Number inputs? Date inputs? Is there a list of those so I know which ones I need to validate manually?

**Edit**: Here's a more specific use case:

```js
function addChar() {
  document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value += 'a';
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" maxlength="5" value="a">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<button onclick="addChar()">Add another character</button>
```

The user might click on the "Add another character" button a couple of times and then submit the form. It will not fail. If I want to prevent the user from adding too many characters, I need to add custom Javascript validation:

```js
function addChar() {
  var input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
  if(input.value.length > input.maxLength) {
    return;
  }
  input.value += 'a';
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" maxlength="5" value="a">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
 <button onclick="addChar()">Add another character</button>
```

And now, there's validation for `maxlength` two times in the code. This does not seem right and inconsistent compared to other validit restraints (like number input `max` above)

Comment: Well you also need to validate backend XD (if you have one)

Comment: Don't rely on client side form validation.

Comment: @PEPEGA sure, but imo that is no reason why frontend validation should be allowed to be errorneous.

Comment: And for the user the html validation already prevents typing more than the maxlength

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel For typing, yes. But when the user adds characters with javascript buttons, the validation needs to be repeated. I added another example to illustrate.

Comment: `maxlength` attribute applies only to `input` and `textarea` elements.

Comment: @RobMoll That is an input element.

Comment: @phil294 I know. You asked which elements it applies to.

Comment: @RobMoll that was max, however, not me. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For certain `input` types, [the `pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) can be most useful in this particular situation, because as you have identified, the spec treats `maxlength` and `minlength` differently as it comes to Constraint Validation.

Both `minlength` and `maxlength` require user input for the `dirty value flag` to be raised, triggering an invalid state, and thus forcing the validation on submit. Setting the value via a script does not raise the flag:

- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-maxlength
- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-dirty
- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#constraints

However, the `pattern` attribute doesn't have this unique requirement and thus will be validated on form submit, so it seems, see the example below:

```js
function addChar() {
  var input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
  input.value += 'a';
}
```

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 1px solid crimson;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" value="a" pattern=".{1,5}" title="You may only include a maximum of 5 characters.">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<button onclick="addChar()">Add another character</button>
```

Comment: Pattern is a nice solution. Unfortunately, it does not apply to textarea elements.

Comment: @phil294 JS to the rescue for `textarea` unfortunately. But if you are trying to set the value via JS or the value attribute, it's not much more effort. Though, if you setting via `value` that seems to be under the developer control anyway.